# I would love me having this question answered

Tags: sentence

I've recently happened to use following sentence:

> ```
> I would love me having this picture.
> ```

Instead of usual:

> I would love to have this picture

Was that a proper sentence? Does it have different meaning than the second one? It has no equivalent in my native language, so I had to pick it up somehow. Google search provided me with just a few such word usages. Might it be some kind of slang?

Comment: The differences are slight. In general, the first one is less common and not correct and when people use it, they are generally being ironic or facetious.

Comment: @: The first example isn't "not correct" - it's syntactically identical to, for example, [*It makes him happy and **I like him being happy**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+like+him+being%22) All you can say is that *idiomatically*, OP's specific example is "non-idiomatic". Which may be because the subject of the participial clause is ***me*** - or perhaps some other reason, I dunno.

Comment: @FF I'll say it's grammatical but unacceptable (as with the Chomsky example).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That looks like an interesting topic, thanks for mentioning it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both sentences are correct. The difference in meaning is subtle: the first emphasizes that the speaker wants the picture for himself instead of another obtaining it.

The grammatical construction, *me having this picture*, in the first sentence is what is known as a participial clause, consisting of a subject (me) and a participle or a participial phrase. Participial clauses (and infinitive clauses, discussed elsewhere) are odd in that the subject will take a case based on the clause's function in the sentence (here the direct object of *love*) rather than on the subject's role as subject; hence, the objective *me*.